# Type not recognized with generics method in Kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, generics, kotlin

I have this interface with this generic method:

```
interface IInterface {
    fun <T> test(body: T)
}
```

I want to implement this interface like this:

```
class MyClass: IInterface {
    override fun <JsonObject> test(body: JsonObject) {
        if (body is com.google.gson.JsonObject) {

        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is type JsonObject not recognized like "com.google.gson.JsonObject". So i can write this code without error in my compilator (intelliJ).

```
override fun <NotExistingClass__> test(body: NotExistingClass__) {
```

So, how to define the type of T for JsonObject from Gson ? this code does not work:

```
override fun <com.google.gson.JsonObject> test(body: com.google.gson.JsonObject)
```

Thank's

Comment: in your case, you need using the generic class instead of using the generic method.

Answer (score 2):

This `interface`:

```
interface IInterface {
    fun <T> test(body: T)
}
```

is not generic, but it has a *generic method*. If you want to make it generic do this:

```
interface IInterface<T> {
    fun test(body: T)
}
```

then your implementation will look like this:

```
class MyClass: IInterface<JsonObject> {
    override fun test(body: JsonObject) {
        if (body is com.google.gson.JsonObject) {

        }
    }
}
```

If you still want a generic method for some reason you'll have to pass the generic type parameter at each call site:

```
someInstance.test<JsonObject>(obj)
```

Comment: Because you want to pass the generic type parameter to the method *in its declaration*. You can only pass parameters to it at the call site.